# Flex Dynamic object name, and add object to object?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, object

I have this situation where i'm trying to save "chat logs" while people switch around views in my flex mobile application..

so, my plan is i'm starting out with a main object that I plan to re-use as the main chat log object..I call it `textObj`

so, when someone new wants to chat my plan is to make a new object with the persons username

so how if i were to get the username from something like data.username how could I translate that into the var name of the object I want to make? So in the end i end up with

```
var uniqueUsername:Object = new Object();
```

so I can eventually do something like

```
uniqueUsername.chatLog="Sample text log";
```

EDIT: I guess I wasn't clear I dont literally mean uniqueUsername as the username....

say `data.username` was equal to `AwesomeDudeYeah`

and I wanted to make

```
var AwesomeDudeYeah:Object = new Object();
```

I cant just do

```
var data.username:Object = new Object();
```

so how could I make that work?

I want to make the username how I refer to the chat logs inside the textObj

Then how would I go about adding that to the textObj obj?

So i end up with `textObj.uniqueUsername.chatLog="Sample text log";`

which i could reference by doing `textObj[uniqueUsername][chatLog]`

(at least I think thats how it would be done)

Any help on these topics would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bracket notation

```
var textObj:object = new Object();
textObj[uniqueUsername].chatLog = "Sample text log";


//accessed by
textObj[uniqueUsername].chatLog
```

if uniqueUsername does not exist in the textObj then you will get errors so make sure you handle them

```
    textObj[uniqueUsername] //basically if this is undefioned or null

//then when you do 
 textObj[uniqueUsername].chatLog // is trying to find chatLog on a null/undefined object
```

The error gods will smite you down

[EDIT]
After reading your comments with Jax I think you should rework it a bit and make it more readable

```
var aUsers:Array = new Array( );

var oUser:Object = new Objbect();
    oUser.name = uniqueUsername;
    oUser.chatLog = "Sample text log";

aUsers.push( oUser );
```

Personally I would make a user class and hold user data in that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how I can make the username an object var. And the EDIT of your posts seems like the solution I might go with for now, I think making an array and pushing the object in the array seems to be what i was actually thinking. And its the best bet for what I understand about programming. If i understand what you meant by a user class to hold data in I'd definitely try it, but i really have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 1):

First, let me mention that using untyped object is not a good idea.  You're essentially making 'data soup' which is hard to code with, to debug, will probably create null exceptions on runtime and will slow down your development efficiency.  You should be using typed classes to create your objects (create a User class with a log and name property, etc).

However, the answer to your question:

```
var textObj:Object = {}; // if not instanciated already
textObj.uniqueUsername = {chatLog:'Sample Text Log'};

// Or you can do it all in one line
var textObj:Object = {uniqueUsername:{chatLog:'Sample Text Log'}};
```

You get the idea, however, this is not recommened.

Comment: EDIT: I guess I wasn't clear I dont literally mean uniqueUsername as the username....

say `data.username` was equal to `AwesomeDudeYeah`

and I wanted to make

    var AwesomeDudeYeah:Object = new Object();

I cant just do

    var data.username:Object = new Object();

so how could I make that work?

I want to make the username how I refer to the chat logs inside the textObj

Comment: well, it depends what you mean by 'equal to AwesomeDudeYear'. is that a string? another object? You'll probably just want to do an associative array with `obj[enterStringNameHere] = {};`, but again, this is a ludicrous way of doing it.  Might as well create a User class that holds the name or have a Dictionary holds the instance of the User through a key (the username).